# Floyd's Algorithm implemented in Python. two dimensional print array

Tags: python, printing

I am attempting to print my python program that implements floyds algorithm.

```
n=5
    for k in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for i in range(n):
                if A[i][k]+A[k][j]<A[i][j]:
                    A[i][j]=A[i][k]+A[k][j]
```

I am trying to print the solution in the same format as below: (not including the first column and row)

```
  0 1 2 3 4
  -----------
0|0 1 4 500 3
1|1 0 2 500 4
2|4 2 0 1   5
3|500 500 1 0 3
4|3 4 5 3   0
```

500 indicates infinity

Any ideas? I am hoping indices will do the trick.

Also does anyone know the order of magnitude of this algorithm?

Comment: The post is a little bit messy... Maybe you could edit it? Take into account that hitting the enter will exit the code sample {}. Hit enter while holding the caps. Once I see that maybe we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this.

```
>>> A = [[0, 1, 4, 500, 3], [1, 0, 2, 500, 4],[4,2,0,1,5],[500,500,1,0,3],[3,4,5,3,0]]
>>> for elem in A:
        print "\t".join(['Inf' if val == 500 else str(val) for val in elem])


0   1   4   Inf 3
1   0   2   Inf 4
4   2   0   1   5
Inf Inf 1   0   3
3   4   5   3   0
```

Comment: this is what i got when i ran the program. why?                       0 1 3 4 3
1 0 2 3 4
3 2 0 1 4
4 3 1 0 3
3 4 4 3 0

Comment: I don't know about the algorithm. Are you implementing it right?

Comment: i believe so. i used the program from above.

Comment: Are there supposed to be two similar nested loops? for j in range(n)

Comment: oh no but even when that is changed to i it does not produce the indicated

Comment: @user2627901 : There must be something wrong with your implementation of the algorithm, then. The printing has nothing to do with it and is being handled seperately.

Comment: any idea what that could be?

Comment: Your code seems to agree with some webpages I have checked, why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: Yes, your code gives the correct answer for the example in: http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/105104098/TransportationII/mod13/16slide.htm  . Check your initial numbers and your results!

Comment: it has to print the following order  -----------
0|0 1 4 500 3
1|1 0 2 500 4
2|4 2 0 1   5
3|500 500 1 0 3
4|3 4 5 3   0

Comment: @user2627901 : It does print that, I just replaced 500 with Inf.